# cannot invoke getjsonobject(int) on the primitive type int

Tags: android, json, primitive-types

Can someone help me on this...

I'm just trying to make these lines of codes work. At `menuitemArray.length().getJSONObject(i)` it gives me the error, `"cannot invoke getjsonobject(int) on the primitive type int"`

Here's the code :

```
private void parse(TextView txtResult) throws Exception{
    jObject = new JSONObject(xResult);

    JSONArray menuitemArray = jObject.getJSONArray("message");
    String sret = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < menuitemArray.length(); i++){
        sret +=menuitemArray.length().getJSONObject(i).getString("username") + " : ";

        System.out.println(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i)
            .getString("username"));

        System.out.println(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i)
            .getString("subject"));

        sret +=menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i)
            .getString("subject") + "\n";
    }
    txtResult.setText(sret);
}
```

And yeah, I'm kinda new to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 sret +=menuitemArray.length().getJSONObject(i).getString("username") + " : ";
```

to

```
 sret +=menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("username") + " : ";
```

Actually **sret** is an String variable. And you're trying to get `username` from the length of **menuitemArray**.

Comment: Ah, yeah, i see, i guess it's just a newbie mistake... thank you very much... It solved the problem...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  private void parse(TextView txtResult) throws Exception{
        jObject = new JSONObject(xResult);
    
        JSONArray menuitemArray = jObject.getJSONArray("message");
        String sret = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < menuitemArray.length(); i++){
            sret +=menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("username").toString()+" : ";
    
            System.out.println(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i)
                .getString("username"));
    
            System.out.println(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i)
                .getString("subject"));
    
            sret +=menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i)
                .getString("subject")+"\n";
        }
        txtResult.setText(sret);
    }
```